# Is there a way to save and retrieve files while selenium tests are running in Azure Hosted Agent?

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I have a suite of Selenium Tests that run inside Windows 2019 Azure Hosted Agent. Each Test captures an image of a particular web page.

For future test runs these images will be used as a baseline when comparing the current/actual state of a web page.

Is there a way to save and retrieve these baseline images somewhere when tests are running in the hosted agent?

Notes:

- Currently I am using a workaround so I can save and upload the baseline images generated from the hosted agent. Force the tests to fail and attach the images in the test results via `TestContext.AddResultFile.` Then download each image and save it to local repo and then sync in azure repo. I don't want to do this any longer because there are hundreds of images to be generated already.
- I can't use the baseline images generated from my local machine because the hosted agent has a different viewport. Hence, the image comparison will always find a difference between the baseline and actual.

Comment: comparing images is not a great idea.  There can be differences regarding font rendering for instance... (rounding when smoothing text for display)  Having said that, you can store all images as base-64 in a single html page for cataloging the whole test in one file.

Comment: @pcalkins This is not a viable solution for us. We tried converting and comparing the images as base64 strings and it took a longer time (+1 min average) to execute each test. But thank you for your insight.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check out below answer? How did it go?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT yes. I just accepted the answer, sorry. I was able to do it on my end. I can now easily update and add baseline images when needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you saved your screenshots to hosted agent via selenium. You can publish the test screenshots to azure pipeline build artifacts via [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops). See below example:

TestMethod:

```
 webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
 webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
 webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(test_url);
           
 Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)webDriver).GetScreenshot();
 
# create a screenshots directory to save the screenshots.
Directory.CreateDirectory("screenshots");
 
 string attachmentsPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" +"screenshots"+"\\" +
            "testName1.png";

 # save the screenshot to the screenshots directory.
 screenshot.SaveAsFile(attachmentsPath);
                    
 Assert.AreEqual(webDriver.Title,"Google");
 webDriver.Quit();
```

Above code will save the screenshot to folder `screenshots` folder.

Then you can add a copy files task to copy the screenshots to folder `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
    Contents: '**\screenshots\**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    flattenFolders: true
```

And then. Add Publish Build Artifacts task to publish the screenshots to build artifact.

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: screenshots'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: screenshots
```

After your pipeline build is complete. You can download the screenshots directly from the summary page.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for but I am accepting this answer because this is a better workaround for getting images captured from the azure hosted agent.